# Checking if browser is in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check if a browser is currently in fullscreen mode (after the user pressed f11)?

Something like:

```
if (window.fullscreen) {
  // it's fullscreen!
}
else {
  // not fs!
}
```

Thanks.

Steerpike's answer is pretty good, but my comment:

> Thanks a lot, but this answer is not
> sufficient for FF. In Chrome I can set
> a small tolerance, but in FF the
> urlbar and tabs takes a while to
> disappear, which means after pressing
> f11, the detected window.innerWidth is
> still too small.

Comment: **You could also use `document.fullscreenElement` to get element if it exists else it will be `null`. Inner- and screen width are not reliable, for example, if you open dev tools the inner sizes will not be the same as screen sizes. You can assign `document.onfullscreenchange` to this method to get an instant response when changing between fullscreen and off.**

Comment: There's an API now:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Answer (score 38, accepted):

***WARNING:*** This answer was posted for a very old version of Firefox. Your answer is probably not here, keep looking.

---

In Firefox 3, window.fullScreen works (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.fullScreen).

So, you could potentially do something like this:

```
if((window.fullScreen) ||
   (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: *Just an fyi:* this (the second half) won't work if you have your browser's web console open, which you *do*, because you *are* testing this.  Additionally, at least as of 2017, the implementation of the Fullscreen API in *all* browsers is about as consistent as winning the lottery.

Comment: Ye gods, this answer was posted for Firefox 3, almost 7 years ago (Sometimes I think there needs to be an expiration date on accepted answers here). I'm both surprised and not surprised they don't have a standard yet. Even the [CSS Stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) is still experimental.

Comment: AS of `18 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement

Comment: `fullscreenElement` only works for JS triggered fullscreen, not user pressing F11.

Comment: Does not work if something like Dev Console is open.

Comment: Also doesn't work when zoomed in/out..

Comment: @gaspar of course it doesn't work. This answer was posted in 2010. There are people learning to program who weren't born when this was posted.

Comment: I used `document.fullscreenElement` and the window's width and height and it worked well, even when the user uses `F11`.

Comment: @Nick can you write an answer with your solution code?

Comment: I used a conditional for `document.fullscreenElement`:

"if (document.fullscreenElement != null) {
   document.exitFullscreen();
} else {
   document.body.requestFullscreen();
}"

Answer (score 41):

This works for all new browsers :

```
if (!window.screenTop && !window.screenY) {
    alert('Browser is in fullscreen');
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but can you be more specific about "new"?

Comment: Tested in IE8, FF3.6, FF12. Works in all of them.

Comment: In chrome maximized also triggers this.

Comment: With .screenLeft instead of .screenY it works better (in Win8/IE10)

Comment: Doesn't work if a user has no top panel.

Comment: No, not true, on Windows if you attach your browser window right to top of the screen, that condition will be true as well.

Comment: does not work for chrome today

Comment: Does not work for me; when the window is maximized, window.screenTop == 0 (chrome 54).

Comment: Not working for firefox in android

Comment: This does not consider whether the window is full width, nor does it distinguish full height windows from windows in full screen mode.

Comment: This solution is unreliable when using external monitor(s)

Comment: Also moot on mobile !

Comment: This works in a Quasar/Electron app.. which is good enough for my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

```
if(window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height) {

} else {

}
```

(Warning: The browser chrome may muck with the height comparisons but the width checks should be pretty spot on)

Comment: I expect you'll want to have some margin of difference, since some browsers still have a couple of pixels at the top reserved for a bar that will slide down when you hover over it, which will throw off this check.

Comment: Yeah, the check definitely needs some tolerance. Other than that: +1

Comment: Don't forget that `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` are [not supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#windowview) by IE.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this answer is not sufficient for FF. In Chrome I can set a small tolerance, but in FF the urlbar and tabs takes a while to disappear, which means after pressing f11, the detected window.innerWidth is still too small.

Comment: You could still admit a bigger tolerance, as most of the browser have at least an address bar, you can guess that the height difference could be of n pixels.

Comment: OK, yes you're right... why did I think that... Sorry, way too late! A value of 63px worked for me.

Comment: You should consider window.outerHeight as it's more reliable for detecting if browser is at MaxHeight compared to screen.height

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up with following solution:

```
function _fullscreenEnabled() {
    // FF provides nice flag, maybe others will add support for this later on?
    if(window['fullScreen'] !== undefined) {
      return window.fullScreen;
    }
    // 5px height margin, just in case (needed by e.g. IE)
    var heightMargin = 5;
    if($.browser.webkit && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor)) {
      // Safari in full screen mode shows the navigation bar, 
      // which is 40px  
      heightMargin = 42;
    }
    return screen.width == window.innerWidth &&
        Math.abs(screen.height - window.innerHeight) < heightMargin;
  }
```

Which works in every browser I care about (Chrome, FF, IE, Safari/Mac, Opera).

Update: It doesn't work on Opera/Mac, Opera on Mac while in full screen mode hides only the 'common' OSX menu, thus height differs only by few pixels which is too dangerous for me.

Comment: It doesn't work with chromium (on linux) and multiple screens -- screen.width/height seems to report the primary screen size, even if the page is fullscreen on the secondary monitor.

Comment: on chrome/linux, "if($.browser.webkit" breaks

Comment: This requires JQuery to function.

Answer (score 0):

this works on major browsers (ie,ff,opera,chrome)

```
function isFullscreen(){

  if($.browser.opera){

    var fs=$('<div class="fullscreen"></div>');
    $('body').append(fs);

    var check=fs.css('display')=='block';
    fs.remove();

    return check;
  }

  var st=screen.top || screen.availTop || window.screenTop;

  if(st!=window.screenY){

    return false;
  }

  return window.fullScreen==true || screen.height-document.documentElement.clientHeight<=30;
}
```

css for opera:

```
.fullscreen { display: none; }

@media all and (view-mode: fullscreen){

  .fullscreen { display: block; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple enough: Find the browser viewport using `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`, and if they conform to a set of defined viewport sizes (600 x 480, 1280 x 800, etc.), then you can know that it is most likely fullscreen. Also you can set event handlers for like the `fll` key and other possible shortcuts to define browser fullscreen.

Comment: window.outerHeight  and  window.outerWidth indicate the browser window outer dimensions. 

window.screen.height  and  window screen.width  indicate the display dimensions of the current display panel. 

If these two width/height pairs are equal and indicate reasonable values (such as both indicating 1920x1200) then Full Screen can be assumed for that browser.