# Javascript: check if window.fullScreen is false then open url in new window in full screen

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written a javascript on page load that

```
if(!window.fullScreen) window.open(document.URL,'','fullScreen=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');}
```

but window.fullScreen always come false so it keep opening window.

any other way to check if window is in full screen mode or not?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that you open the new window but don't set the original fullscreen flag, so if the first page is in fullscreen you never open anything, whan not you're opening more and more pages. Not a JS developer, but you can try to add window.fullscreen = true after opening the new window...

Comment: this question has been discussed in this forum:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863351/checking-if-browser-is-in-fullscreen

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047319/detecting-if-a-browser-is-in-full-screen-mode

Comment: just wondering, why you want to achieve this? Opening a new window just because its not in full screen mode doesn't seem to be a good ux practice.

Comment: @vincenzo windows.fullscreen will always return false inspite of setting it to true

Comment: @Falaque please read the question before commenting :D

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the opening bracket

```
    if(!window.fullScreen){//<- Forgot opening bracket
    window.open(document.URL,'','fullScreen=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
    }
```