# Fullscreen no vertical scrollbar with bootstrap markdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I'm using Bootstrap Markdown on my site. In the demo [here](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/), when I enter fullscreen, my browser's scrollbar (Firefox) disappears. However, on my site this does not happen (the scrollbar sticks around). I am wondering how exactly the demo is accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assume this is part of your browsers settings but if you want to accomplish it with javascript it is actually very simple

```
//Check for fullscreen
if ((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)){
    document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden"
} else {
    document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
}
```

I used this [Checking if browser is in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863351/checking-if-browser-is-in-fullscreen) post to figure out how to determine if the window was fullscreen so you can refer to that for further information on that.