# How to check full opening window by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know the way to check full opening of window by Javascript?

```
    // code1 dont work
    $(window).resize(function() {
        ...
    });

    // code2 dont work
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        ...
    }
```

I wanna check the MOMENT when screen(of browser) go to fullscreen.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "full opening window"?

Comment: This seems to be addressed in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863351/checking-if-browser-is-in-fullscreen

Comment: Its not exactly right. I wanna check the MOMENT when screen(of browser) go to fullscreen.

Comment: onresize should do it. How much of a delay are you observing? Is it firing too early? Too late? Also, in case it helps, remember there's a CSS media query for the fullscreen state.

Comment: You mean AFTER resizing has finished? Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing

Comment: Ty all! SetTimeout is good helper here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `outerHeight` and `outerWidth` of the window against the `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight`

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (window.outerWidth === screen.availWidth && window.outerHeight === screen.availHeight) {
        console.log("This is your MOMENT of fullscreen: " + Date());    
}
```

Comment: I have some problems if panel of console is open here. Size of window changing then..But its not ctitical thing.

Comment: I tested this in Chrome. Console view wouldn't effect the code since we are dealing with outerHeight and outerWidth.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( window.innerHeight == screen.height) {
    // browser is fullscreen
}
```

For the event see: [Fullscreen API: Which events are fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621499/fullscreen-api-which-events-are-fired)